# Gobble optional arguments

Tags: macros, best-practices, optional-arguments

You can use `\@gobble`, for instance, to restrict the usage of a macro like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cmd}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}
  \let\cmd\@gobble
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cmd{Hello World!}
\cmd{Again...}%not desirable
\end{document}
```

But, if you have a command with an optional argument, e.g. `\newcommand{\cmd}[2][]{#1 #2}`, there is no kernel macro that helps you. Sure, you could define something like

```
\newcommand{\@gobble@opt}[2][]{}
%\newcommand{\RG@gobble@opt}[2][]{}%alt: to avoid possible name clashes
```

Is this the usual way? Is it, generally speaking, absurd to gobble like this?

Comment: `\let\cmd\@gobble` is not really sufficient: you should add something more with `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\gobblemyopt}[2][]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\cmd}[2][]{%
#1 #2%
\GlobalLetLtxMacro\cmd\gobblemyopt
}
```

I have another solution, simpler and without usepackage:

```
\let\cmdnotyetrun=\iftrue
\newcommand*{\cmd}[2][]{\cmdnotyetrun%
#1#2%
\global\let\cmdnotyetrun=\iffalse\fi}%
```

Comment: @cgnieder Not really important here since neither `\\cmd` will be needed nor `\\gobblemyopt` will be changed again. But it won’t hurt either.

Comment: There is `\GlobalLetLtxMacro`. `\global\LetLtxMacro` won’t work. It might be helpful, if you also add that `\usepackage{letltxmacro}` is needed.